# Java TimeZone and Linux TimeZone Daylight Savings doesnot match

Tags: java, timezone, posix, dst

I need to create POSIX format of TimeZone as defined by the following format.

```
std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]
```

For ex for "America/New_York" the POSIX format is
 EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2

Now the value M3.2.0/2 is represented in the form Mm.w.d/t.

This specifies day d of week w of month m. The day d must be between 0 (Sunday) and 6. The week w must be between 1 and 5; week 1 is the first week in which day d occurs, and week 5 specifies the last d day in the month. The month m should be between 1 and 12. I borrowed the above explanation from the following link

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

So the above example states, the normal offset from UTC is 5 hours; since this is west of the prime meridian, the sign is positive. Summer time begins on March’s second Sunday at 2:00am and ends on November’s first Sunday at 2:00am.

When I check this in Linux timezone file /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York, it matches the above value

EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0

However when I construct this in java for timezone "America/New_York" I get the following string

EST-5EDT+1,M2.1.1/2,M10.1.1/2

I constructed the above string by extracting the information from the output of the following code.

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
System.out.println(timezone.toString());
```

The output is as below

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]
```

Notice the values endMonth=10 which should be 11 as compared to Linux output.

Comment: Can you post a link to the POSIX doc for this format? I am curious.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in the description, its as follows
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

Comment: Thanks, but No, that's not the official POSIX documentation. That is just some library at gnu.org. Googling led me to other sources documenting a different definition of this supposed POSIX date-time format. So I was hoping someone might post an authoritative source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the output of `toString` is not advisable, since there are no contractual guarantees about its format in either the TimeZone or SimpleTimeZone classes.

Obviously, your month numbers are off by one;  the week of the month isn’t quite as simple, since you need to take into account the first full week of the month.

I would use Java’s documented public methods to get the information:

```
static String posixSpecFor(TimeZone tz) {
    Formatter posixSpec = new Formatter();

    float offset = (float) tz.getRawOffset() / (1000 * 60 * 60) * -1;
    posixSpec.format("%s%s%s",
        tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT),
        offset >= 0 ? "+" : "",
        new DecimalFormat("0.##").format(offset));

    if (tz.observesDaylightTime()) {
        posixSpec.format("%s", tz.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
    }

    ZoneId zone = tz.toZoneId();

    TemporalField weekOfMonth =
        WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 7).weekOfMonth();
    int thisYear = Year.now(zone).getValue();

    List<ZoneOffsetTransitionRule> rules =
        zone.getRules().getTransitionRules();
    if (rules.size() > 2) {
        rules = rules.subList(0, 2);
    }

    for (ZoneOffsetTransitionRule rule : rules) {
        posixSpec.format(",M%d.%d.%d/%s",
            rule.getMonth().getValue(),
            rule.createTransition(thisYear).getDateTimeBefore().get(
                weekOfMonth),
            rule.getDayOfWeek().getValue() % 7,
            rule.getLocalTime());
    }

    return posixSpec.toString();
}
```

Comment: Great!!!! I used inputs from your code and was able to construct following string

EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2

Thanx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the complete code that I am using to construct Posix timezone string

public class PosixTimeZone {

```
public String toPosixTZ(String timezoneStr) {

    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneStr);
    sop("timezoneStr", timezoneStr);
    String posixTX = "";

    PosixTimeZoneData pTZData = new PosixTimeZoneData(timezone);
    if (timezone.useDaylightTime()) {
        posixTX = getPosixDSString(pTZData);
    } else {
        posixTX = getPosixString(pTZData);
    }
    return posixTX;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Posix TimeZone is " + new PosixTimeZone().toPosixTZ(args[0]));
}

private void sop(String varname, String meesage) {
    System.out.println("**************: " + varname + " = " + meesage);
}

private String getPosixDSString(PosixTimeZoneData pTZData) {
    String posixString = "";

    if ((pTZData.std != null && !pTZData.std.isEmpty())
            && (pTZData.stdOffset != null)//&& !pTZData.stdOffset.isEmpty())
            && (pTZData.dst != null && !pTZData.dst.isEmpty())
            && (pTZData.dstOffset != null)// && !pTZData.dstOffset.isEmpty())
            && (pTZData.start != null && !pTZData.start.isEmpty())
            && (pTZData.end != null && !pTZData.end.isEmpty())) {
        posixString = String.format("%s%s%s%s,%s,%s", pTZData.std, pTZData.stdOffset, pTZData.dst,
                pTZData.dstOffset, pTZData.start, pTZData.end);
    } else {
        sop("Error", "Invalid Parameters");
    }

    return posixString;
}

private String getPosixString(PosixTimeZoneData pTZData) {
    String posixString = "";

    if ((pTZData.std != null && !pTZData.std.isEmpty())
            && (pTZData.stdOffset != null && !pTZData.stdOffset.isEmpty())) {
        posixString = String.format("%s%s", pTZData.std, pTZData.stdOffset);
    } else {
        sop("Error", "Invalid Parameters");
    }

    return posixString;
}

class PosixTimeZoneData {

    String std = "";
    String stdOffset = "";
    String dst = "";
    String dstOffset = "";
    String start = "";
    String end = "";

    private PosixTimeZoneData(TimeZone timeZone) {

        std = timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
        int rawOffset = (timeZone.getRawOffset() / 3600000) * -1;
        stdOffset = (rawOffset >= 0)
                ? ((rawOffset == 0) || (rawOffset == 1) ? "" : "+" + rawOffset)
                : "" + rawOffset;
        if (timeZone.useDaylightTime()) {
            dst = timeZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT);

            int dstRawOffset = timeZone.getDSTSavings() / 3600000;
            dstOffset = (dstRawOffset >= 0)
                    ? ((dstRawOffset == 0) || (dstRawOffset == 1) ? "" : "+" + dstRawOffset)
                    : "" + dstRawOffset;

            ZoneId zone = timeZone.toZoneId();

            TemporalField weekOfMonth
                    = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 7).weekOfMonth();
            int thisYear = Year.now(zone).getValue();

            List<ZoneOffsetTransitionRule> rules
                    = zone.getRules().getTransitionRules();
            if (rules != null && !rules.isEmpty()) {
                if (rules.size() > 2) {
                    rules = rules.subList(0, 2);
                }

                start = String.format("M%d.%d.%d/%s",
                        rules.get(0).getMonth().getValue(),
                        rules.get(0).createTransition(thisYear).getDateTimeBefore().get(
                        weekOfMonth),
                        rules.get(0).getDayOfWeek().getValue() % 7,
                        rules.get(0).getLocalTime().getHour());

                end = String.format("M%d.%d.%d/%s",
                        rules.get(1).getMonth().getValue(),
                        rules.get(1).createTransition(thisYear).getDateTimeBefore().get(
                        weekOfMonth),
                        rules.get(1).getDayOfWeek().getValue() % 7,
                        rules.get(1).getLocalTime().getHour());

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: No need to check if `rules` is null.  The [method’s contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getTransitionRules--) states that it returns “an immutable list of transition rules, not null.”

Comment: Ok. Will change it. Thanx.